# extracting attribute value in XML using regex

Tags: java, regex, groovy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE ... ]> 
<abc-config version="THIS" id="abc">
...
</abc-config>
```

Hi all,

In the code above, how can I extract the value of version attribute using Regex in Groovy/Java?

Thanks.

Comment: There's something you should know... I don't know how to say this, but... be prepared for 10,000 lectures.  Oh, and welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: If by 'regex' you mean 'XPath', then you've come to the right place.

Comment: I meant regex, not XPath

Comment: Thanks, but using regex is a requirement. I do not want to use Xpath.

Comment: one way I can think of is to split the string at version=" and then again at " id=", but this seems sloppy and I am wondering if there is a better regex?

Comment: Unless this is a college assignment aimed at teaching regex, then why id using a regex a requirement? Surely the real requirement is to get the data of interest out of the XML in an elegant fashion? Regex will not help you achieve this goal.

Answer (score 2):

A regex to handle this could be something like:

```
/<\?xml version="([0-9.]+)"/
```

I'll spare you one of the 10000 lectures about not using a regex to parse markup languages.

**Edit:** [The One whose Name cannot be expressed in the Basic Multilingual Plane, He compelled me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: I have read on many occasions how it is not good to use RegEx to parse HTML or XML but I am compelled to do so since XmlParser, XmlSlurper, DOM, SAX nothing seems to be parsing my XML file which has a DOCTYPE declaration. Can you suggest a way around this?

Comment: Post a question asking about that specific problem. Loads of properly-formed documents have DOCTYPE declarations and can be parsed.

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for a regex, but what's wrong with this in Groovy?

Assuming the xml is something like:

```
def xml= '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE abc-config>
<abc-config version="THIS" id="abc">
  <node></node>
</abc-config>'''
```

Then I can parse it with:

```
def n = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml )
```

And then this line:

```
println n.@version
```

Prints out "THIS"

---

If you are having [problems with a more complex DOCTYPE failing to load](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/XmlParser-XmlSlurper-howto-disable-DTD-validation-td353673.html), you can try disabling the DOCTYPE checker by either:

```
def parser = new XmlSlurper()
parser.setFeature( "http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false )
parser.setFeature( "http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false )
parser.parseText( xml )
```

or by using [the constructor for XmlSlurper that takes 2 parameters](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html#XmlSlurper%28boolean,%20boolean%29) so as to disable this checking

Answer (score 0):

Not a java regex, Perl regex...
`/<\w+\s+[^>]*?(?<=\s)version\s*=\s*["'](.+?)["'][^>]*?\s*\/?>/sg`

Note that this fails on many levels, I could fill the page with a proper regex, but I don't have the desire.

this fails too ...
`/<\w+\s+[^>]*?(?<=\s)version\s*=\s*(".+?"|'.+?')[^>]*?\s*\/?>/sg`

so does this
`/<\w+\s+[^>]*?(?<=\s)version\s*=\s*(["'])(.+?)\1[^>]*?\s*\/?>/sg`

Comment: I am not looking for something so complicated and something that I cant understand, but many thanks

Comment: @minirasher - "something so complicated that cannot be understood" is pretty much regex's raison d'etre